# Nominal/Ordinal categories xlim limit in maptlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to set a maximum xlim for a matplotlib seaborn plot, using pylab.

My code is as follows:

```
fig, ax = pylab.subplots(figsize=(20, 12))
ax = sns.pointplot(x="state", y="incomeTotal", data=df2, color="red")
ax = sns.pointplot(x="state", y="incomeTotal", data=df3, color="purple")
ax = sns.pointplot(x="state", y="incomeTotal", data=df4, color="yellow")
#ax = sns.pointplot(x="state", y="incomeTotal", data=df5, color="green")

p1 = patches.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 2, fc="red")
p2 = patches.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 2, fc="purple")
p3 = patches.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 2, fc="yellow")
p4 = patches.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 2, fc="green")

pylab.xlim(['Iowa','Indiana'])
```

This is four seaborn lineplots.

My issue is, Seaborn automatically curtails pointplots at the least maximum point for all four of your plots. One of my lineplots stops at an earlier ordinal value than the others. I want the plot to show all the plots all the way to their limits, even if there is space at the extreme of the chartspace where some of the charts -- but not all - don't have data. So I want to set the xlim, but for an ordinal, not a numeric value.

How can I do this?

I hope this is clear.

Comment: You could pass `order` to each of your pointplots. Or combine the DataFrames and use `factorplot`.